# DataAnnotations RegularExpression - disallow URLs

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying to create a DataAnnotation Regular Expression in ASP.NET MVC that will catch and disallow user-entered URLs. Basically, I want to catch any string that starts with http:// or https:// but my knowledge of Regular Expressions is weak. I can match strings that DO contain those strings with the following regex code:

^(http://|https://)

but I don't know how to negate it, so that, in my model,

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)", ErrorMessage = "Entry should not contain url.")]
```

returns a Model error if http:// or https:// is found at the beginning of the string.

I found the following:

[RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*?(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?).*$", ErrorMessage = "Entry should not contain url.")]

which catches URLs, but it doesn't allow periods in the string

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead anchored at the beginning:

```
@"^(?!https?://).*$"
```

If no full string match is required, this would do:

```
@"^(?!https?://)"
```

Here is [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F!https%3F%3A%2F%2F).*%5Cr%3F%24&i=http%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com%0D%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com%0D%0Ayahoo.com&o=m).

Note that `@"^(?!https?://)"` contains the negative lookahead `(?!https?://)` that stands right after `^` (the beginning of a string). So, it just checks - right at the beginning of the string - if the string does not start with `http://` or `https://` (due to the `?` quantifier set after `s`, we can match both alternatives).

The regex you "found" - `^(?!.*?(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?).*$` - contains a much more complex lookahead restriction. You can [read what it is doing at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zG5pJ1/1). The problem with periods arises due to the periods inside the character class and `\.` - if you type 2 periods and then a comma, this will already invalidate the restriction. It could be used as a regex checking that a string should not contain a URL, you need to check if it does not start with `https?://`.